# Cucumber <reference> in Background?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

Here is a tricky one regarding Cucumber:

```
Feature: Some feature

Background:
    Given I am on the root page

Scenario Outline: Relevant flash messages should appear
    When I fill in some_field with: <name>
    Then I should see the text: <relevant_flash>

    Examples:
        | name          | relevant_flash    |
        | Some name     | Some message      |

Scenario Outline: Irrelevant flash messages should not appear
    When I fill in some_field with: <name>
    Then I should not see the text: <irrelevant_flash>

    Examples:
        | name          | irrelevant_flash  |
        | Some name     | Some message      |
```

I hate having to repeat:

```
 When I fill in some_field with: <name>
```

But for obvious reasons it can not just be moved into background. Or can it? Let me know if you have a workaround...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I can simplify your cucumber with something like this:

```
Feature: Some feature

 Scenario Outline: Relevant flash messages should appear
    Given I am on the root page
    When I fill in some_field with: <name>
    Then I should see <message>
  Examples:
        |        name           |        message        |
        | Some name             | Relevant message      |
        | Some other name       | Irrelevant message    |
        | Some another name     | another flash message |
```

You notice that I take out the `Background:` since we got it cover on `Scenario Outline:`
I think this steps will run and simple with out too much repeatation

Answer (score 0):

Your Scenario outline could be better organized to avoid duplicate, by combining both successful and failed messages together.

```
Feature: Some feature

Background:
    Given I am on the root page

Scenario Outline: Relevant flash messages should appear
    When I fill in some_field with: <name>
    Then I should see <relevant_message>

    Examples:
        | name                  | relevant_flash     |
        | Some name             | Some message       |
        | Some irrelevant name  | Irrelevant message |
        | Name for blank msg    |                    |
```